gnuplot plot 3D polygon but not show
When drawing a triangle using Gnuplot, it does not display. The script is as follows
set xrange [ 36.00000 : 38.30000 ]
set yrange [ 37.9 : 38.40000 ]
set zrange [ -23635.4 : 1000.00000 ] 

set view 69,74

set object 1 polygon from 38.204, 38.3317, 0 to 38.1886, 38.3191, 0 to 38.2011, 38.3339, -1969.62 to 38.204, 38.3317, 0 fillstyle transparent solid 0.5

splot 1/0 notitle

And there is an error prompt for All points z value undefined, I know what this represents
I hope to use Gnuplot to draw a series of triangular meshes based on a series of three-dimensional coordinates

Which gnuplot version are you using? "... series of three-dimensional coordinates...", how exactly would your input data look like?

Your z range is so large compared to the coordinates shown, maybe the polygon is drawn but is so small you don't notice it?  Try set zrange [0:50].

But my actual range of Z values is so large, isn't it correct to set it to [0:50]? Or is there a parameter similar to scale that can be set?

@theozh In fact, I want to implement a command similar to the patch (X, Y, Z, C), create the polymers in 3-D coordinates using X, Y, and Z. To view the polymers in a 3-D view, use the view (3) in Matlab C determines the color. Therefore, I tried the script above.

@Ethan Thank you for your suggestion. I have now displayed the grid by adjusting the range of Z values, but there are still a few issues: 1. The current range of Z is -0.4 to 0.4, but the Z-axis in the figure is not in this range. It seems that the minimum value has changed to -1.0. How can I display the range I have set? 2. I want to know if there is a way to set a property value for each object polygon, and then automatically draw the color of each polygon based on the property value and color band? Thank you again

By default in a 3D plot gnuplot adds extra space at the bottom so that the "floor" is entirely below the plot content.  You can turn off this extra space with the command set xyplane 0.

To remove the gap between the "floor" of a 3D plot (gnuplot calls it the xy  plane) use command
set xyplane 0

Choose a palette color scheme and a range of values that it applies to.  Often (but not always) this is the same as the range of z value you expect.
set palette viridis
set cbrange [0:10]    # blue at 0; yellow at 10

You can assign the color of each polygon either to match its z value, as some numerical value in the cbrange, or as a fraction of the total palette range:
set obj 1 fc palette z        # color is based on z-value
set obj 2 fc palette cb 15    # color assigned to cb=15
set obj 3 fc palette frac 0.5 # half-way through the palette range

For more information help colorspec
No colorbox showing with plot
The color box is shown only if the plot itself uses palette colors. Your plot command splot 1/0 does not.  Try changing it to splot 1/0 linecolor palette.

Thank you for your guidance. Now I can set the color I want for each polygon, but I cannot display the colorbox on my image. Even after trying the following script, it still doesn't workset palette viridis
set cbrange [1 : 2208]
set cblabel "Score"
set colorbox horizontal origin 0,0 size 0.5,0.25
set colorbox vertical
